# form_tag with remote:true, ajax is not working

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am having a `view_file` for view a particular 'Ad' details in that page. within that i want to add rating `div` along with `form_tag`. how can i use it? and implement the `AJAX` with this `form submit`. please guide me. thanks in advance.

Comment: Post some code my friend.

Comment: This is way too vague.

Comment: post some code @Gayathri from the view page and controller.

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation on select_tag](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/select_tag)

```
select_tag( "my_tag_id", get_ids(@entity), class: "progress_and_message",
  data: {
    remote: true,
    url: url_for( action: :my_controller_action, id: my_id)
    // application symbols
    progress_bar: "progress_bar_div_id",
    update: "message_div_id"
  }
)
```

Also, don't forget to

```
//= require jquery_ujs
```

in your application.js